# If Textbox.Value = ("",<0,>1,OR <>"x") Then

Tags: if-statement, userform

When building an IF Then statement, I want to call attention to a textbox when the user form data entered is NOT one of the three approved options (1,0, or X)...

What is the best way to write that?

Here's what I have:

```
If Textbox.Value = ("",<0,>1,OR <>"x") Then 
   Textbox.BackColor = rgbPink
   Textboxlabel.ForeColor = rgbRed
   Textbox.SetFocus
   Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: I think I found my answer! 

If TextBox.Value <> "1" Or TextBox.Value <> "0" Or TextBox.Value <> "x" Then

It seems to test just fine. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score -1):

you want "if not equal to" ? in this case you should use `<>` :

```
If Textbox.Value <>"" OR Textbox.Value<>0 OR Textbox.Value<>1 OR Textbox.Value<>"x" Then 
   Textbox.BackColor = rgbPink
   Textboxlabel.ForeColor = rgbRed
   Textbox.SetFocus
   Exit Sub
End If
```

This will enter in the "if" if `Textbox.value` is different of "", or 0, or 1 or "x"....

Comment: That's sounds closer to what I want....If I use the <> before the parenthesis, would I take out the reference to a blank entry and the less then and greater than signs? So like this...

    <> (0,1, OR "x")

Do I put the 0 and 1 in quotes? Is the use of OR correct?

Comment: I have edit my post, you should try and understand if it correspond to what you want.... here some explanation about if statement : http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-if-statement/ https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/or_vba.php does it resolve ?

Comment: Is that `if...` correct? Try the case when `Textbox.Value` is `0` then `Textbox.Value<>1` and the two string compares will all be true. Try the case when `Textbox.Value` is `1` then `Textbox.Value<>0` and the two string compares will all be true. Try similarly for `Textbox.Value` being either of the string values. Conclusion: the whole condition will never be false. Not sure of the syntax, but the statement should be something like `If not(Textbox.Value="" OR Textbox.Value=0 OR Textbox.Value=1 OR Textbox.Value="x") Then ...`

Comment: Please have a read of [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).